# Rails YAML data location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I want to store a list of U.S. States in a YAML file instead of inside a class/module, where would be the best place to put such a file?

I'm guessing somewhere within config. I would like to know the **best practice** for where such a file would go.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would probably be the /config directory, as you said.

If you have a lot of configuration files and things need to get more granular, then it might be better to organize these into sub-directories of /config. Other than that, I don't see any reason why /config wouldn't be appropriate.

I maintain an internal gem used extensively within a number of my employer's products, and we put "data" based configuration information of this sort in /config/data, but the choice is really yours.